# Hide button on view based on Auth access in Aspnet MVC - Without hard coding Authorization in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authorization

Project Overview:
Working in dashboard Views on back-end of project. I have a Permission driven Menu. Menu gets populated when User logs in and views dashboard. Currently the User sees all the buttons IE: delete, edit, details, create. I would like to hide those buttons from the view. Currently they can select it and it will redirect to a UnAuthorized page if they do not have access.

I have a Menu / MenuPermissions tables that bits are set if the user has access or not. I am looking for something to utilize this information to hide the buttons.

I have created a ActionLink Extension with a couple of classes to turn a bit true or False, but it requires me to have

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administration")]
```

in the controller action. This not desirable as i have the flexibility to edit, create, and delete Roles.

I have looked at several Tutorials and they all seem to relate to Asp.Net Core, which my project is not and do not need it to be.

I found what i needed in this post:
[asp-net-how-to-hide-or-show-a-link-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668261/asp-net-mvc-how-to-hide-or-show-a-link-button-based-on-logged-in-users-role-p)

However it is an incomplete Question - There is no answer to this question that was accepted. Apparently the person has figured it out but did not bother to show what he did..

This is the ActionLink extension example i have tried:

```
 @Html.ActionLinkAuthorized("Edit Roles", "Edit", "Roles", new { UserName = item.UserName }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning btn-sm" }, true)
```

This, Like i said requires the controller to have it set as Authorized. 
The Code below is used as a OnActionExecuting(context) Which is past the point that i would need it. However could help in finding a usable solution.

```
string userid = Env.GetUserInfo("userid");
            string roleid = Env.GetUserInfo("roleid");
            var descriptor = context.ActionDescriptor;
            var actionName = descriptor.ActionName.ToLower();
            var controllerName = descriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName.ToLower();

            var GetOrPost = context.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod.ToString();
            var checkAreaName = context.HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"];
```

The Next two areas aid in finding if the user is authorized based on menu permissions:

```
 private bool IsActionNameEqualToCrudPageName(string actionName)
    {
        bool ActionIsCrud = false;
        switch (actionName)
        {
            case "add":
                ActionIsCrud = true;
                break;
            case "create":
                ActionIsCrud = true;
                break;
            case "index":
                ActionIsCrud = true;
                break;
            case "details":
                ActionIsCrud = true;
                break;
            case "edit":
                ActionIsCrud = true;
                break;
            case "multiviewindex":
                ActionIsCrud = true;
                break;
            case "delete":
                ActionIsCrud = true;
                break;
            default:
                ActionIsCrud = false;
                break;
        }

        return ActionIsCrud;
    }

    private void CheckAccessOfPageAction(ActionExecutingContext context, string actionName, MenuOfRole checkRoleUrlCrud)
    {
        switch (actionName)
        {
            case "add":
                if (checkRoleUrlCrud.IsAdd == false)//Check Crud
                {
                    UnAuthoRedirect(context);
                }
                break;
            case "create":
                if (checkRoleUrlCrud.IsCreate == false)//Check Crud
                {
                    UnAuthoRedirect(context);
                }
                break;
            case "index":
                if (checkRoleUrlCrud.IsRead == false)//Check Crud
                {
                    UnAuthoRedirect(context);
                }
                break;
            case "details":
                if (checkRoleUrlCrud.IsRead == false)//Check Crud
                {
                    UnAuthoRedirect(context);
                }
                break;
            case "edit":
                if (checkRoleUrlCrud.IsUpdate == false)//Check Crud
                {
                    UnAuthoRedirect(context);
                }
                break;
            case "multiviewindex":
                if (checkRoleUrlCrud.IsUpdate == false)//Check Crud
                {
                    UnAuthoRedirect(context);
                }
                break;
            case "delete":
                if (checkRoleUrlCrud.IsDelete == false)//Check Crud
                {
                    UnAuthoRedirect(context);
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

The code that is below is in the class that is used to hide the button - Again it requires that the Authorize is set in the Controller.

```
public static bool ActionAuthorized(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName)
    {
        ControllerBase controllerBase = string.IsNullOrEmpty(controllerName) ? htmlHelper.ViewContext.Controller : htmlHelper.GetControllerByName(controllerName);
        ControllerContext controllerContext = new ControllerContext(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext, controllerBase);
        ControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor = new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(controllerContext.Controller.GetType());
        ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor = controllerDescriptor.FindAction(controllerContext, actionName);

        if (actionDescriptor == null)
            return false;

        FilterInfo filters = new FilterInfo(FilterProviders.Providers.GetFilters(controllerContext, actionDescriptor));

        AuthorizationContext authorizationContext = new AuthorizationContext(controllerContext, actionDescriptor);
        foreach (IAuthorizationFilter authorizationFilter in filters.AuthorizationFilters)
        {
            authorizationFilter.OnAuthorization(authorizationContext);
            if (authorizationContext.Result != null)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Then there are link extensions to use in another file.

If someone could point me in the right direction as to how i can use the code i already have to check menu permissions and then hide the button without hard-coding, It would be appreciated. Or if there is a simpler way of doing this that would also work.

The end result is to get rid of the redirect. My project does not like it because it tries to pass headers after headers are already set - Via "Log-Out".

Thanks for your help on this.

UPDATE:

This has been resolved in another post i posted. 
[stackoverflow.com/questions/11668261](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60154227/the-proper-way-to-get-contents-of-an-array-as-viewbag-item)

Answer (score 0):

I do this the same way as the highly upvoted in the question you linked to.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11668462/5367916

A very simplified version:

**.cshtml**

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
  <button>Admin power button</button>
}
```

The downside of this is that it means there is no automatic link between your implementation:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

and your check in the cshtml. I at least make it strongly typed by using enums and custom attributes and methods for my securables in my role-based security implementation.

```
@if (User.HasSecurable(Securable.AdminPower))
{
  <button>Admin power button</button>
}
```

```
[AllowSecurables(Securable.AdminPower)]
public ActionResult AdminPower()
{
}
```

Comment: Yes this is currently one way i have achieved this in the past. However i do not want to hard code. If i create a role and want that role to have permissions or not, I do not want to have to go through the code again and hard code. Then re-deploy. I need the flexibility. As time goes on i may change things and it would be easier to do it on the back-end and less messy! Thanks for the input though..

Comment: Yes, that's why I use a securable approach. Each function is considered a securable. So maybe creating a new user is one securable. Maybe uploading files is another. I then map securables to roles in the database. So securables are defined once and never change (unless the function is removed), and I am free to manually update the roles as I please.

Comment: If possible, do you have a good link for this Securable? I am not familiar with it.