# The proper way to get contents of an array as Viewbag item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I decided to post a different question for this. This question relates to another post. 
[stackoverflow.com/questions/60141639/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60141639/hide-button-on-view-based-on-auth-access-in-aspnet-mvc-without-hard-coding-aut)

I posted this yesterday. I have found an area in the project where i can achieve what i want pretty easily, I just need the proper way to go about it..

I have a BaseController that all the controllers in the Dashboard relate too. In this i have a

```
 protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
```

In this i am grabbing several things UserId, RoleId etc. It also has a line of code that returns an array of objects / permissions.

```
 var menuaccess = (MenuOfRole[])global;
```

And MenuOfRole is this:

```
private class MenuOfRole
{
    public string MenuURL { get; set; }
    public string RoleId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdd { get; set; }
    public bool IsCreate { get; set; }
    public bool IsRead { get; set; }
    public bool IsUpdate { get; set; }
    public bool IsDelete { get; set; }
}
```

I am only interested in the Bools as i am trying to Hide buttons on my view that only show if user has access too.

So i tried to use it like this:

```
ViewBag.Menu = menuaccess;
```

And then in my view i did an if statement:

```
@if (ViewBag.Menu.IsUpdate == true)
```

However it says that System array does not have an IsUpdate. 
When placing breakpoints and viewing the locals MenuOfRole comes back with the list and the result of either being true or false.

So my question is, Is there a way i can call this and use it in my view? Either with a viewBag or some other means? Since this is already doing all the work i need, i really do not need to have a session and do another check just for the buttons.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Update: This seems to be working for this. I am not sure if it is the proper way to do this or not but it is working..

Utilizing this that already exists

```
var GetOrPost = context.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod.ToString();
```

Added this:

```
if (GetOrPost == "GET")
{
    if (actionName == "add" || actionName == "index" || actionName == "create" || actionName == "edit" || actionName == "delete" || actionName == "multiviewindex")
    {
       ViewBag.Add = menuaccess.FirstOrDefault(i => (i.IsAdd));
       ViewBag.Read = menuaccess.FirstOrDefault(i => (i.IsRead));
       ViewBag.Create = menuaccess.FirstOrDefault(i => (i.IsCreate));
       ViewBag.Edit = menuaccess.FirstOrDefault(i => (i.IsUpdate));
       ViewBag.Delete = menuaccess.FirstOrDefault(i => (i.IsDelete));
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on this? I just want to make sure i am doing this properly and not hindering the performance..

This is what i am doing in the view for the button..

```
@if (ViewBag.Edit = true) { 
   @Ajax.ModalDialogActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Edit User", "btn btn-warning btn-sm", new { UserName = item.UserName })
}
```

UPDATE:
This needs more work.. MenuOfRoles brings back everything the Role has permission to. So i need a way to specify which one i am on. I am thinking that in each controller add something to check. I have to think about this one!

Comment: You assign an _array_ of `MenuOfRole` objects to `ViewBag.Menu`. The array itself has no `IsUpdate` property - only the items inside the array. Do you want to know if _any_ item in the array has that property true? Or _all_ of them?

Comment: I am going to need each one individually. So if IsUpdate is false then it would hide the edit button. If IsCreate is false then it would hide the Create button. and so on..

Comment: So somewhere you need to loop over the contents of `ViewBag.Menu` and check the property of each item. Without knowing how those items and buttons are connected there's not much more that can be added.

Comment: They will connected by the if statement. The way it is done with the menu items is it loops through but also displays the menu items as an array if the item is true for IsForNavbar. I really do not want to have an array of buttons because the buttons have parameters and it would be a lot of work trying to get that to work properly.

Comment: I don't know how to help from here - you have a collection of items, so I'm guessing that for each button you somehow need to find the appropriate item in the array that corresponds to the button, then check the `IsUpdate` value of that item. Without more knowledge of the overall view and model that's about all I can tell you.

Comment: I added code that seems to be working, above. Not sure if it is correct but it is working.

Comment: is `MenuOfRole` unique per menu item, or is it unique per role?

Comment: Unique per role. It basically does a check on the Logged in user against the MenuPermissions table where the roleId and paermissions for each of these are set per Controller / Action. I could post the whole OnActionExecuting snippet for clarity, however it is doing a lot and is a bit lengthy..